# Oracle SQL*Loader timestamp is error

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

My control file is

```
ACCESS_TIME TERMINATED BY "" "TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(:ACCESS_TIME,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS:FF TZR')"
```

Data file is

```
2012/11/12 15:18:00:765 CST
```

But when I run SQL*Loader to commit the data, in the database ACCESS_TIME does not match data file.

```
2012/11/13 05:18:00:765000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're seeing that behaviour then the table column must be time stamp with local time zone and you are in Singapore etc (gmt +8) eg:

```
SQL> alter session set time_zone='+08:00';

Session altered.

SQL> create table test (access_time timestamp with local time zone);

Table created.

SQL> host sqlldr test/test control=/tmp/load.ctl log=/tmp/load.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Mon Nov 12 13:26:14 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 2

SQL> select * from test;

ACCESS_TIME
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
13-NOV-12 05.18.00.765000

SQL> alter session set time_zone='-06:00';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from test;

ACCESS_TIME
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
12-NOV-12 15.18.00.765000

SQL> host cat /tmp/load.ctl
load data
 infile *
 replace
 into table test
 (  ACCESS_TIME terminated by "" "TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(:ACCESS_TIME,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS:FF TZR')"
 )
begindata
2012/11/12 15:18:00:765 CST
```

if you want to preserve the CST part and not convert it then define your table as TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE.

```
SQL> create table test (access_time timestamp with time zone);

Table created.

SQL> host sqlldr test/test control=/tmp/load.ctl log=/tmp/load.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Mon Nov 12 13:27:56 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 2

SQL> select * from test;

ACCESS_TIME

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
12-NOV-12 15.18.00.765000 CST
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a:

```
select SESSIONTIMEZONE from dual;
```

You insert your data in Central Standard Time. When you select the data it is probably displayed in your sessions (local) timezone.